# I need help identifying the characters on this artist’s seal (Characters identified: 南海)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]I have this cool tshirt from the 1990’s and really want to know who is the artist. I actually lived in Guangdong for 4 years and have asked some friends but they cannot help. So… translation software doesn’t help either. I would be grateful for anyone’s input.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like “南凌” to me. But the instead of 凌 with two dots on the left it uses older version with 3 dots on the left 淩

Comment: it's maybe 藩南 in seal script